# Creating filter using lambda is producing bool Error

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to filter out value "UNK" from column payment_type and return the complete dataframe. I'd like to use an anonymous function. I'm getting a Type Error.

I've tried creating a separate function, but still not able to make it work. I'm running this on Jupyter Notebooks

```
paymentGroups = fareData.groupby("payment_type")

filteredPaymentTypes = paymentGroups.filter(lambda x: 
                                   x["payment_type"].values != 'UNK')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: filter function returned a ndarray, but expected a scalar bool
```

The desired result is a modified dataframe without rows that include "UNK" in payment_type column.

Comment: how about `fareData[~fareData['payment_type'].eq('UNK')]` I dont see any reason for groups. If I am wrong, please add a sample data and a desired output dataframe. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `lambda x: x["payment_type"] != 'UNK'`?

Comment: try x["payment_type"] instead of x["payment_type"].values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not filtering out the values before the group by with a simple `mask`?

```
mask = fareData.payment_type != 'UNK'
fareData = fareData[mask]
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filtering with `groupby` is needed when the selection condition relates to some
property of the **whole group**, e.g. the mean value of some column (within the
current group) > *some_value*.

But in your case the selection criterion relates to a single column in the
**current record** (not in the group), so grouping is not needed.
Use `query` instead, e.g.:

```
fareData.query("payment_type != 'UNK'")
```

## Edit

If for some reason you still want to use grouping, note that in this case
the filtering is on the grouping key (`payment_type`), which is **the same**
in each row of the current group.

So the filterning condition can check the value of interest only in the
**first row** of the current group:

```
paymentGroups.filter(lambda x: x['payment_type'].iloc[0] != 'UNK')
```